# Cannot connect to remote visualsvn server (https) from inside corporate network

Tags: svn, firewall, visualsvn-server

We have a remote svn server (visualsvn server) that we connect to through https.

We do not have any problems connecting from our office but we only have a very basic firewall.

We are trying to connect from another location but think that their firewall may be getting in the way.  What rule would need to be added to the firewall to allow this to work?

The format of the url is

```
https://myserver.com:8443/svn/repo/trunk
```

Wing

Comment: Its a fair bet that they are blocking something. It could be port 8443 is blocked somewhere (this bit after the : in the URL) 443 is the standard HTTPS port which stands a better chance of success and you could try to bring up your svn server on the standard https port

Comment: So if we unblock 8443 then it should work.  We will give it a go.